# Android socket.close() causes "the system call was canceled"?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, exception, android-lifecycle

My MainActivity starts another thread called UdpListener. In onResume, the thread will be started (this works), in onPause it should stop, but socket.close() causes an error message in LogCat "**the system call was canceled**". The UdpListener itself works fine in JUnit tests so this must be some kind of Android problem.

These are the corresponding methods of my thread:

```
private void setThreadRunning(boolean running) throws MyOwnException {
    this.running = running;

    if (running) {
        try {
            serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9800);
        } 
        catch (SocketException e) {
            exceptionThrown = true;
            this.running = false;
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());

            if (serverSocket != null && !serverSocket.isClosed())  {
                serverSocket.close();
            }

            throw new MyOwnException(e);
        }
    } 
    else {
        if (serverSocket != null && !serverSocket.isClosed())  {
            serverSocket.close();
        }
    }
}

public void stopThread() throws MyOwnException {
    setThreadRunning(false);
}
```

MainActivity.onPause():

```
@Override
public void onPause()  {
    super.onPause();

    try {
        udpListener.stopThread();
    } 
    catch (MyOwnException e) {
        //TODO AlertDialog
    }
}
```

serverSocket.close() of else branch will be executed and causes the LogCat entry, but why?

**UPDATE**
Maybe Dalvik recognize this as error because close() throws SocketExceptions on every thread currently block in "receive", but I'm not sure if this Exception is related to this problem.

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#close%28%29)

Comment: what do you mean why? when you call stopThread() it closes your socket in the else branch. What's the permissions in your manifest file?

Comment: It closes the socket, but it causes an error (LogCat displays it as error), as I said. My permissions are WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and INTERNET but I don't think its a permission problem, because why should I be able start the thread then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I surround the receive() call in run method with a SocketException try..catch, the error doesn't occure anymore. I guess that my exception handling had some side effect to cause this error.